# Upload document to Google Drive using an express app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, multer

**Goal**

The user of my webapp can upload one (or several) file(s) through a form directly to a Google Drive. This does not concern the user's Google Drive, but a Google Drive dedicated to the webapp. The user will then have access to the uploaded files; this access is password protected.

**Status**

Locally I am able to make it work, but after deploying it to Heroku it starts getting issues with the upload. Authentication is not an issue, neither the part where the user gets access.

**Approach**

1. Uploaded files (through a form) are read using multer and stored in a local folder (the root folder of the project)
2. This local files are accessed and the Google Drive API (drive.files.create({})) is used to save them to the drive
3. The local files are then removed again

**Problem**

I cannot seem to store the uploaded file on the server and therefore cannot access it when using drive.files.create({}). The following error is logged when the app crashes:

> sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted"
> method=POST path="/upload_file" host=printme.herokuapp.com
> request_id=1141e08f-8e38-42ac-b41e-a97aaf515f45 fwd="194.127.172.71"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=503 bytes=252
> protocol=https

**Code**

Multer code (app.js):

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, ".");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
  },
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: Storage,
}).array("file", 5); 

app.locals.upload = upload
```

Multer upload function (called from POST request containing files)

```
function multerUpload(req, res) {
  console.log("Start multerUpload")
  req.app.locals.upload(req, res, function (err) {
    const random_string = randomString()
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.end("Something went wrong");
    } 
    else 
    {
      const drive = req.app.locals.gdrive
      console.log("Start loop")
      req.files.map(item => {
        storeFile(random_string, item, drive, req) // See code of function below
      })
      console.log("End loop")
    }
  })
}
```

Store function to store files on Google Drive

```
function storeFile(random_string, item, drive, req) {
  console.log('Loop item')
  const fileMetadata = {
    name: random_string + "_" + item.originalname,  // Sets filename in gdrive
    parents: [req.app.locals.gdrive_dir_printme],   // Sets folder in gdrive
  };
  const media = {
    mimeType: item.mimetype,
    body: fs.createReadStream(item.path),
  };
  drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: "id",
  },
  (err, file) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } 
    else {
      console.log('File stored')
      console.log(file.data)
      fs.unlinkSync(item.path)
    }
  })
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi ! So you did manage to upload these files to your Drive using Drive API when you tested this on your local environment right? Are you getting any error message on the console? Is the part that is failing exclusively ```Drive.files.create()```? If you could provide a sample code with *no sensitive data* of how you are uploading the file to Drive it could be helpful to debug it. Thanks !

Comment: Hi Mateo, thanks for your reply! Yes, that is correct. When I run the app locally, I have no issues. After deploying it, the uploads don't work anymore. I have added the code I use, as well as the error I get, to the question. Thanks again!